# Can I understand and play System Shock 2 without playing the original title or knowing much about it?

Tags: system-shock-2, system-shock

I saw that System Shock 2 was [on sale at GOG](http://www.gog.com/game/system_shock_2), and got interested. Can I realistically play the game and follow on the plot without prior playing of the original? How connected are they?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Yes.**

The introduction to SS2 recounts the story of SS1.

While there are callbacks, and of course, the games share a universe, you don't need any background to just jump right in with the sequel.

Comment: The only downside would be that it lessens the shock of the big reveal. ("Who is she anyway?" versus "Wow, so she was behind all of this?")

Comment: I did not play System Shock and when I played SS2 in '99 I was shocked at Shodan's reveal. The game gives you enough information for it to be ...well shocking. :D